# Undocumented parameter in C# Word Cloud library

Tags: c#

I have been using this library (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wordcloud) to generate a word cloud image. However, I have noticed that for every word in the 'words' parameter it has a 'frequencies' parameter. I cannot find any documentation on this 'frequencies' parameter and my tests haven't been able to yield any results. Can anyone provide any information on this please?

```
using WordCloudGen = WordCloud.WordCloud;

var wc = new WordCloudGen(width, height);

wc.Draw(words, frequencies);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter `words` provides a list of unique words of the text as `List<string>`.
The second parameter frequencies contains the number of occurrences of each word in the text as `List<int>`.

E.g. given the text "*hello world hello world, world, world*" should be transformed to
`words = {"hello", "world"}` und `frequencies = {2, 4}`. With this data the WordCloud-algorithm is able to draw the word "world" two times bigger than "hello".